# ¿Cómo controlar el evento click de un "Item" concreto de un "NavigationView" usando "NavigationUI"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigationview, navigation-drawer

En mi `Activity` tengo declarado un `NavigationView` que contiene un `Menu` con una serie de "Items", en el `onCreate()` tengo el siguiente código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityLauncherBinding activityLauncherBinding =
        ActivityLauncherBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

    setContentView(activityLauncherBinding.getRoot());

    toolbar = activityLauncherBinding.toolbar;
    drawerLayout = activityLauncherBinding.drawerLayout;
    navigationView = activityLauncherBinding.navigationView;

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    navHostFragment =
        (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigationHostFragment);

    assert navHostFragment != null;

    navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
    appBarConfiguration =
        new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
            .setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)
            .build();

    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);

    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this::onDestinationChangedListener);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    getLegalGuardianPreferences(sharedPreferences);
}
```

Y para controlar las acciones sobre el "Menú lateral" tengo implementada la siguiente función:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
        || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

El caso es que para uno de los "Items" quiero darle un funcionamiento distinto, ya que no tiene "Fragment" propio y sólo muestra un "Dialog", lo he hecho así:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navigationLogout) {
        createLogoutDialog();
        return true;
    } else {
      return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
        || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Pero cuando estoy en modo "Run" no hace nada, ni siquiera muestra un error y "Debug" tampoco se muestra ningún error y no se para en el punto de interrupción que he colocado, ya sea que no pasa por el `if` de este último método o por algo que se me escapa.

Mi pregunta es si pueden coexistir "NavigationUI" con una implementación independiente para la funcionalidad de uno de los elementos del "Menú", y en ese caso ¿cómo sería la implementación correcta para coexistan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `onOptionsItemSelected` no está haciendo nada. La ejecución no se para en el punto de interrupción porque ese método nunca se llama. Lo que hace funcionar el click de tus items es esta línea

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController)
```

Deberías haber leído su descripión..

> Sets up a `NavigationView` for use with a `NavController`. This will call
> `onNavDestinationSelected` when a menu item is selected.

Ahora si quieres que un item haga algo diferente puedes setear el `OnMenuItemClickListener` directamente sobre el item

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigationLogout).setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
    createLogoutDialog();
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Efectivamente el onOptionsItemSelected no hace nada, lo primero que he hecho es eliminarlo y seguía funcionando todo perfectamente, empecé a usar NavigationUI por artículos que había leido, y no siempre en estaban muy claros. He hecho el cambio y ya me funciona perfetamente. Muchísimas gracias por tu aporte.